# Android SDK "sdkmanager -list" gives a "java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char..." exception

Tags: java, android, exception, nio, android-sdk-manager

I have installed JDK1.8 for Windows and downloaded the Android SDK (command line tools).

I'm on Windows 10, BTW...

Running the command "sdkmanager -list" from "C:\android_command_tools\bin", I get:

```
C:\android_command_tools\bin>sdkmanager
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char at index 116: C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1761649281-4237022023-2634429347-1001\$RDIUE56\App Store Badge Localized\._(Arabic) ???????
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.toPath(FileSystemFileOp.java:284)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.isDirectory(FileSystemFileOp.java:169)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:225)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:201)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:123)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:725)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

I have tried to reinstall JDK.

Anyone got a clue on what is happening here??

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to not install the SDK into a folder with special characters, like Arabic ones or such, also avoid any special charactes (spaces sometimes also count). The safest bet is to install it in "C:/android_sdk" or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed the JDK and JRE in the default directories, which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172"...

Comment: And the Android SDK is in "C:\android_command_tools\" (edit).